# $Z_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+2)$ is a field. Looking for $(2x^2+x+1)^{-1}$ (the inverse element)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$Z_3[x]$/$(x^3+x^2+x+2)$ is a field. Looking for $(2x^2+x+1)^{-1}$ (the inverse element)

So the task was that this is a Field (which I have done), so I need to find the

inverse element, but I can't seem to find how. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068641/multiplicative-inverse-of-2x-3-i-in-mathbbz-5x-i).

Comment: I'm guess by $Z3$ you mean $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Z3 = {0,1,2} with operations:  + modulo 3  and  . modulo 3

Answer (score 1):

Use the extended Euclidean algorithm.
Determine the gcd of $p(x)=x^3+x^2+x+2$ and $f(x)=2x^2+x+1$. It should be 1. Then write the gcd as linear combination of these polynomials: $1=s(x)p(x)+t(x)q(x)$. Then modulo $p(x)$, the polynomial $t(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$.

Comment: which are these functions s(x) , t(x), q(x) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since we mod out by $(x^3+x^2+x+2)$ we get that $x^3+x^2+x+2 = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+2)$.

We are looking for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+2)$ such that:

$ \alpha (2x^2 + x + 1) = 1$

Since $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+2)$ we know $\alpha = ax^2 + b x + c$

Thus, (using the fact that  $x^3+x^2+x+2 = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+2)$ )
\begin{align}
\alpha (2x^2 + x + 1) &= 2ax^4 + (a+2b) x^3 +  (a + b+ 2c) x^2 + (b + c) x + c \\
& = (x^3+x^2+x+2)(2ax+(-a+2b)) + (-b+2c)x^2+(-b+c)x+ 2a-b+c \\
& =  (-b+2c)x^2+(-b+c)x+ 2a-b+c
\end{align}

So, (Using the fact that we are in $\mathbb{Z}_3$)

\begin{align}
&-b+2c = 0 \Rightarrow b = -c \\
& -b+c = 0 \Rightarrow b = c \Rightarrow b=c=0\\ 
& 2a-b+c = 1 \Rightarrow a = 2
\end{align}

Thus $\alpha = 2x^2$.
(It will be a useful exercise to check that this is correct)