# An inverse element of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Given the extension $\dfrac{\mathbb Z_7[x]}{\langle 3+x^3\rangle}:\mathbb Z_7$ and $\alpha =x^2+\langle 3+x^3\rangle \in \dfrac{\mathbb Z_7[x]}{\langle 3+x^3\rangle}$, find $\alpha^{-1}$.

I tried to solve it..

Suppose $\alpha^{-1}=a+bx+cx^2$. Then $1=\alpha^{-1}\alpha =(a+bx+cx^2)x^2=4b+4cx+ax^2$ (because $x^3=-3$).

And then, $a=0,4c=0,4b=1.$ But how do I find $b$?

Is my solution correct??

Comment: I think the solution is $\alpha^{-1}=2x$

Comment: [Here's a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068641/multiplicative-inverse-of-2x-3-i-in-mathbbz-5x-i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is correct.

If $g$ is a nonzero element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, to find its inverse you can use [Bézout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). Since $p$ is prime, then $\gcd(g,p) = 1$ so there are integers $x,y$ such that $gx + py = 1$. Note that this equality in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is equivalent to saying that there is an element $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $gx = 1$, i.e. $g$ has an inverse. To compute it you can use the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Is there an easy way to compute the minimal polynomial $m_\alpha(x)$ knowing this result?

Comment: Computing the minimal polynomial of an element over a field and computing the inverse of said element are two very different questions.

Comment: Oh ok (in my homework these questions are followed one by the other) 

Comment: I assume you are studying Galois Theory?

Comment: that's correct, Galois theory

Comment: There are several ways to compute the minimal polynomial . For instance if $\beta$ is a root of $x^3 + 3$ then $\alpha = \beta^2$. Note that $\mathbb{Z}_7/\langle 3+x^3\rangle := \mathbb{Z}_7(\beta) = \mathbb{Z}_7(\alpha)$ since $\alpha = \beta^2$ and $\beta = 2\alpha^2$. Now $x^3 + 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_7$ so we know the degree of the extension $[\mathbb{Z}_7(\beta):\mathbb{Z}_7] = 3$. That means that $[\mathbb{Z}_7(\alpha):\mathbb{Z}_7] = 3$ so we are looking for a polynomial of degree $3$ such that $\alpha$ is a root. If you play with it a bit you might come to $x^3 - 2$.

Comment: there are many question that I have about this.. I think would be better to post the question and If it's not too much to ask Would you re-answer it with more details?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying coefficient ring is $\mathbb{Z}_7$, so $4b = 1$ has solution $b = 2$. (More specifically, you are solving $4b \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, which can be done by inspection. Or with the Euclidean algorithm, if you prefer).

It is then easy to check your solution (which is apparently $2x$) by multiplying it by $\alpha$ and verifying that you get $1$.